# How to copy all the files in certain Directory and recreate the directory structure using java?

Tags: java, file, directory

Instead of copying one file at a time. I am zipping all the files and unzipping them. I am using the below code to zip and unzip the files, but how do I unzip them and dynamically recreate the directory structure by the file description.
for e.g: if the file is

`c://users//desktop//635289512-251.txt`

I need to place the file in

`c://users//desktop//635_users//2895_access//635289512-251.txt`

Thank you for you help.

```
public static void zip(File directory, File zipfile) throws IOException {
    URI base = directory.toURI();
    Deque<File> queue = new LinkedList<File>();
    queue.push(directory);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipfile);
    Closeable res = out;
    try {
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
        res = zout;
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            directory = queue.pop();
            for (File kid : directory.listFiles()) {
                String name = base.relativize(kid.toURI()).getPath();
                if (kid.isDirectory()) {
                    queue.push(kid);
                    name = name.endsWith("/") ? name : name + "/";
                    zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
                } else {
                    zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
                    copy(kid, zout);
                    zout.closeEntry();
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        res.close();
    }
}

 public static void unzip(File zipfile, File directory) throws IOException {
    ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(zipfile);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zfile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        File file = new File(directory, entry.getName());
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        } else {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            InputStream in = zfile.getInputStream(entry);
            try {
                copy(in, file);
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```